# Can RabbitMQ route messages using an XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath, routes, rabbitmq

Actually, `RabbitMQ` route messages using routing key and headers expression.

Can `RabbitMQ` route messages using an `XPath expression` like an XML content based router?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything out of the box to do `XPath` routing. However, you can go ahead and develop your own `RabbitMQ` plugin to support it. I would recommend to read Chapter 9 of RabbitMQ Cookbook to learn how to do this.